# C recursive program crashes

Tags: c, recursion, crash

I'm a beginner to the whole programming thing and I'm doing programming exercises from a book. I've reached a part of the book where I'm supposed to write recursive functions. Some of the programs crash and I have no idea what am I doing wrong. Please compare these two:

1. This should read a number from keyboard and return number! (factorial of number). It crashes after I try to input the number

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int number, x;
   int factorial (int a);

   int main() {

   printf("Input a nonnegative whole number: \n");
   scanf("%d", &number);

   int x = factorial(number);
   printf("Factorial of %d equals %d", number, x);

   return 0;
   }

   int factorial (int a){
   if(a=0) {
           return 1;
       } else {
           return a*factorial(a-1);
       }
   }
   ```
2. This should read the n from the keyboard and return the value of the n-th element in a string. This one doesn't crash.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int n;
   int string (int a);

   int main() {

       printf("Input a nonnegative whole number: \n");
       scanf("%d", &n);
       int x = string(n);
       printf("%d element of the string equals %d", n, x);

       return 0;
   }

   int string (int a) {
       int value;
       if (a<=1) {
           value = 1;
       } else {
           value = string(a-1) + 2*string(a-2) + 3;
       }
       return value;
   }
   ```

These two programs seem pretty much the same to me. I can't figure out why the first one crashes and the second one doesn't. Please help, thank you in advance.

Comment: `if (a=0)` - take a very close look at that, there's a missing character.

Comment: It's time to learn how to use a debugger, which helps greatly finding such simple problems.

Comment: Some compilers are giving warning on this...

Comment: Wow, ok, that was a simple mistake. Sadly, I didn't get any warnings. Thanks so much everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You used `if(a=0)` but the equal sign here assigns the 0 to a instead of comparing a and 0.
Use `if(a==0)` instead.